# SQL command not properly ended - creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I am receiving the error

> SQL COMMAND NOT PROPERLY ENDED

for the following piece of code:

```
CREATE TABLE klisa.min_invlv_strt_dt AS

SELECT cas_id
    ,min(invlv_strt_dt) min_invlv_strt_dt
FROM kids.tcas_clnt_invlv_hist
WHERE invlv_end_dt IS NULL = --and cas_id = 63878
GROUP BY cas_id
ORDER BY cas_id;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE invlv_end_dt IS NULL = --and cas_id = 63878
```

Formatting your query highlights (literally) the issue.  You have your `--` comment after an `=`, causing the error.

It should be this instead:

```
WHERE invlv_end_dt IS NULL --and cas_id = 63878
```

*(I'm assuming you intended to comment out the `AND` clause)*

Comment: Thank you. I'm super new at this. Now it says I have a missing expression?

Comment: Perhaps remove the `AS` before the `SELECT` statement?  I'm not the greatest at MySQL syntax.

Comment: shouldn't `min(invlv_strt_dt) min_invlv_strt_dt`  be `min(invlv_strt_dt) AS min_invlv_strt_dt` ? ;)

Comment: @TusharGupta `AS` is optional for field/result aliasing.

Comment: @lrk889 The `=` issue was the only thing I could see as well; if you updated it as this answer indication, I can see no reason for the _missing expression_ problem. Perhaps, update your question with what you tried from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting together with the other are saying.  So it's easier for you to see.

```
CREATE TABLE klisa.min_invlv_strt_dt AS
SELECT cas_id, min(invlv_strt_dt) as min_invlv_strt_dt
FROM kids.tcas_clnt_invlv_hist
WHERE invlv_end_dt IS NULL GROUP BY cas_id ORDER BY cas_id;
```

Make sure you are using an ID that has access to both klisa and kids (Schema's)